# Why does the following code not compile, and if replaced with 'int' instead of 'int&', it compiles successfully?

Tags: c++

T&& does not have reference collapsing，and it is causing the following error:

> error: ‘void my_collection::add(T&&) [with T = int&]’ cannot be
> overloaded with ‘void my_collection::add(T&) [with T = int&]’

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <typename T>
struct my_collection
{
    void add(T& thing)
    {
    }
    void add(T&& thing)
    {
        cout << is_lvalue_reference<T>::value << endl;
    }
};
int main(){
        my_collection<int&> a;
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*T&& does not have reference collapsing*" So what do you expect `int&` `&&` to collapse into?

Comment: @康桓瑋 first add T& -> int&& , second add T&&->int&

Comment: `int&` `&` will collapse to `int&`.

Comment: @康桓瑋you are right,thanks